# DS 160 - specific travel plans for an F1 visa?

Tags: visa, student-visa, usa

a question regarding DS-160 forms for a student visa:

I was accepted to study in an american university, starting in august. I have already purchased roundtrip flight tickets, to move to the U.S. in august, and to return home for Christmas (I plan to re-enter the U.S. after New Year's eve).
In the DS-160 forms when applying for a visa, when it's asked if I have specific travel plans, should I answer 'Yes'?

The flight tickets I have make it seem that I only intend to stay for 6 months in the US, but in reality I intend to stay for the whole duration of my studies (4-5 years), and only make short visits to my home country. If I answer 'No' to the question, then I'm able to state the intended length of stay as 5 years, which is more accurate.

Comment: What about the form prevents you from answering both questions accurately? Yes, you have specific travel plans. Your intended length of stay is 5 years (matching your I-20).

Comment: The 'intended length of stay' box only appears when I check 'No'. If I say 'Yes' it only allows me to give the flight details.

Comment: In general you should answer all questions exactly as written. Just because you're doubtful about the form's logic isn't a good reason to answer falsely about whether you have travel plans.